# How to perform CRUD operations on a static JSON array in Angular? (without API)

Tags: json, angular, frontend, angular-reactive-forms, crud

I have this JSON array file.

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "john.doe@example.com",
      "age": 25
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "email": "[jane.doe@example.com]",
      "age": 28
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Bob Smith",
      "email": "[bob.smith@example.com",
      "age": 30
    }
]
```

How do I perform CRUD operations on this array through a Angular Reactive Form and present the data in a table?

I do not have any API. I want to use this Static JSON to perform CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server)? Usually I mock compatible data and I work with this for mvps

Put the following into the db.json file

`db.json`

```json
{
   "users":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"John Doe",
         "email":"john.doe@example.com",
         "age":25
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Jane Doe",
         "email":"[jane.doe@example.com]",
         "age":28
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "name":"Bob Smith",
         "email":"[bob.smith@example.com",
         "age":30
      }
   ]
}
```

run `npx json-server db.json`

trough Angular `HttpClient` you will be able to perform the following HTTP calls:

- GET /users
- POST /users
- PUT /users/{id}
- DELETE /users/{id}
- PATCH /users/{id}

You can also use OData like syntax by visiting the following [url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#params)

For the form I suggest you to visit the [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

For the table I suggest you to take inspiration from something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dev-reusable-generic-table?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgeneric-table%2Fgeneric-table.component.ts).

Linking all together

Once you scaffolded the form, the table and the data service (which will make you able to make your specific HTTP request) you have to:

- perform the PATCH/PUT request through your data service when the user trigger the save action
- once the previous request ends, you will have to update the specific edited row of the table

Comment: I tried but I can't get the API endpoints like put patch delete post etc

Comment: Can you provide some example? It would be much easier in order to help

Comment: I can't provide you the exact example but I have ran the json-server on a localhost and the data were showing as I have put the array but I don't know how to fetch the exact data from that server, neither do i know how to get CRUD operations endpoints from the mock API

Comment: And as for my goal here is rather clear. I want to show the static array data in a table. Then through a form I want to add new data to the table and it will show up with the rest of the data. Then removing or updating those data. Hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: please, have a look to the updated answer. I cannot put all of that in here..